# constructor and prototype

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Can someone explain this?

```
function Foo() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 2;
}

function FooProto() {
    this.arrow = 1;
    this.bow = 1;
}

document.writeln(Foo.prototype); // [object Object] 
document.writeln(Foo.prototype.constructor); // function Foo() { x =1; y=2; }
```

My understanding here is: Foo.prototype is an Object whose constructor property is Function Foo.  Foo.[[Prototype]] is Function.Prototype

```
obj = new Foo;
document.writeln(obj.constructor); // function Foo() { x =1; y=2; }
document.writeln(obj.constructor.prototype); // [object Object]

Foo.prototype = FooProto;

document.writeln(Foo.prototype); // function FooProto() { arrow = 1; bow = 2; }
document.writeln(Foo.prototype.constructor); // function Function() { [native code] }
```

Question 1: How did the look up using [[Prototype]] happen here. I would appreciate if someone can explain this to me.

```
document.writeln(obj.constructor); // function Foo() { x =1; y=2; } .. no change
document.writeln(obj.constructor.prototype); // function FooProto() { arrow = 1; bow = 2; }

anotherObj = new Foo;
document.writeln(anotherObj.constructor); // function Function() { [native code] }
document.writeln(anotherObj.constructor.prototype); // function Empty() {}
```

Question 2: Same question as Question 1. How did the Javascript interpreter perform the lookup?

Answer (score 5):

When explaining prototype-based code, it is much simpler to use `Object.create` to explain stuff. `Object.create` is a function that receives a prototype object and creates a new instance object that has the prototype object as its [[prototype]]

**When looking up properties in an object is work like this:**

Every object has its own and immutable [[prototype]] property inside. This property is secret and hidden, unless you are in Firefox, where you can get it via `__proto__`.

When *reading* a property up we first search for it in the object itself and if we don't find it there we recursively search for the object's [[prototype]].

When *writing* a property we always write an own-property (we never mutate the [[prototype]], even if it also has the property we are setting).

```
proto = {a:1};
child1 = Object.create(proto);
child2 = Object.create(proto);

child1.a = 2;

console.log(proto.a);  //1
console.log(child1.a); //2
console.log(child2.a); //1
```

**When creating a function**

Whenever we create a function object in Javascript, it comes with a `prototype` property already filled in. This `prototype` is an object (inheriting from Object.prototype) and has the `constructor` property set to the corresponding function.

**When instantiating an object using a function constructor (new Foo)**

A new object is created with the functions `prototype` as its [[prototype]] and the function is run o the object to initialize it.

---

1. I don´t really want to explain what is going on in the first case, since the 
   `Foo.prototype = FooProto;` part doesn't really make sense and is probably not what you wanted to do (remember that prototypes should be objects, not functions)
2. As for the second case, changing the `prototype` property of the constructor function will only affect the future instances (anotherObj). The [[prototype]] property of the already created objects is secret and immutable so there is nothing you can do to change them.

   - Note that if you want to dynamically change the prototype and existing objects (monkey-patching) you can do that by writing and overwriting values in the existing prototype object instead of replacing it with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There're two concepts of prototype in Javascript. (I take it as a name collision in language design.)

1. The prototype in the "**prototype chain**". 
   It is a inside property as mentioned in the last answer. The prefered way to access it is `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

   ```
   var a = {};
   Object.getPrototypeOf(a); // Object {}
   Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)); // null, the top of prototype chain.
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)); // the methods inherited
   ```
2. Every **constructor** (I think acutally every function declared) has a own property "prototype". It come to use in the `new` operator.

> > The `new` operator does 2 steps.
> >
> > > 1. First is to create an object whose prototype (the 1st one, saying, [[Prototype]]) is assigned as the constructor's prototype (the 2nd one).
> > > 2. Second is to run the constructor (looking up from `prototype.constructor`) with taking the created object as implicit argument `this`.

Now to your case:

The first `obj` was created with its property [[Prototype]] (**proto** in some engines) assigned as Foo.prototype.

```
obj.constructor === obj.__proto__.constructor === Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo
obj.constructor.prototype === Function.prototype
```

Note that the constructor is also a Function object.

Then you changed the prototype of `Foo`. This changed the `obj.constructor.prototype` but not `obj.constructor` which has a different reference. The `anotherObj` had a new [[Prototype]] from the following `new` operator.

This question has been here for years. Following readers may be also confused as me. I recommendated the newly published book *Speaking JavaScript* from Dr. Axel Rauschmayer :

[Terminology: The Two Prototypes](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch17.html#two_prototypes)